# dynamically embedding forms

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am trying to do add embedding forms dynamically using a single table in my schema.

What i mean by this is, in my `sfGuardUserProfile` table, I have numerous fields to determine what a user is, i.e. practice_id, nurse_id, patient_id

So, with that in mind, i am trying to dynamically add nurses to practices.

I have a practice form, that extends `sfGuardUserAdminForm`, which extends `sfGuardUser`, this is so i can get the username, password etc stored in the `sfGuardUser` table.

Within my `practiceForm` I am embedding a `practiceProfileform`, which displays the fields i need from the `sfGuardUserProfile` table. I hope everyone is following...

This works fine and I see the fields from both tables.

Now, the bit i am now unsure how to do: embedding the nurses. I am particularly unsure how to do this, as the practices and nurses are to be saved in the same table.

practiceForm

```
class Practiceform extends sfGuardUserAdminForm 
{
    public function configure()
    {
       $form = new PracticeProfileForm($this->getObject()->getProfile());
       $this->embedForm('profile', $form);
    }
}
```

I also have a nurseForm, which again extends `sfGuardUser`, embeds a nurseProfileForm, which extends `sfGuardUserProfile` to get the fields i need.

nurseForm

```
class dentistForm extends sfGuardUserAdminForm 
{
    public function configure()
    {
       $profileForm = new nurseProfileForm($this->object->Profile);
       $this->embedForm('profile', $profileForm);

{
```

}

My schema.yml is as follows:

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(11)
      notnull: true
      default:
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      unique: false
      autoincrement: false
    email_new:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    firstname:
      type: string(255)
    lastname:
      type: string(255)
    practice_id:
      type: integer(11)
    nurse_name:
      type: varchar(255)
    practice_name:
      type: varchar(255)
    practice_type:
      type: varchar(255)
    validate_at:
      type: timestamp
    validate:
      type: string(33)
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile
   Practice:
      class: sfGuardUserProfile
      foreign: id
      local: practice_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
  indexes:
    validate:
      fields: [validate]
```

Is there an easy way to achieve adding these nurses dynamically with the schema/forms i currently have using Doctrine/SF1.4?

Manay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest to rethink your schema first. Do you really need to store all the entities in one table?

Instead, have different entities (classes) with their specific fields that relate to sfGuardUser. For example:

```
Nurse:
  columns:
    account_id: integer(4)
    name: string(255)
    ...
  relations:
    Account:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: account_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: one
```

Then, you can embed Nurse relation in your sfGuardUserForm:

```
class sfGuardUserForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
       $this->embedRelation('Nurse');
    }
}
```

Or, the other way around:

```
class NurseForm
{
    public function configure()
    {
       $this->embedRelation('Account');
    }
}
```

And do the same for all the other entities. If you feel however, that your enities are pretty much the same, you can have a look at Doctrine's inheritance, though it is usually frowned upon.